# Can I install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0-desktop on Intel core i7 10 Gen 10700 with ASUS PRIME-H470-PLUS motherboard combination?

Tags: 20.04

Does installation of Ubuntu 20.04.2.0-desktop is supported for ASUS PRIME-H470-PLUS motherboard with Intel core i7 10 Gen 10700?

Comment: try it by booting from a Live DVD https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started

Comment: Firstly note Ubuntu has different products, Ubuntu releases based on *deb* packages for servers & desktop use the *year.month* format, eg Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Ubuntu also has products that are *snap* only intended for *headless* operation which use the *year* format, eg. Ubuntu Core 20 - for use in devices, appliance but also cloud use.  They are different products, ie. Ubuntu Core 20 (like you imply in text) is not the same as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (you tagged).